# Possible to prevent windows from other desktops to pop up?

Tags: linux, i3-window-manager

If I have a chat program on desktop 2 when I am on desktop 1, and it opens a new window, then it pops up on the current desktop (1 in this case), and this I don't want.

## Question

Is it possible to configure i3 so if an application opens a new window, then it says on the same desktop as the parent application?